# IE6 postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6

I have a page that contains a user control that is just a personalized  dropdown list . I assign to each item the attribute `onClick=__doPostBack('actrl',0)`.

when I click the page postback fine and I got the expected results. However in IE6 my page doesn't change to the new values loaded from the server.

The weird thing is that when I shift + click on the link The page reload fine with all changes.

I tried to disable caching on the page but no luck.

using all this code

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
Response.Expires = -1
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Page.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30))
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
Page.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching()
Page.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```

Also when I debug the application I can see that the generated html to be rendered is correct, but it is not rendered.

This problem happens only in IE6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known IE6 bug (#223) with magical HTTP get requests.

See the bug here:
http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/09/bug-223-magical-http-get-requests-in.html

It happens when an inline event handler causes a page change in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE6 is not reloading the page from the server (its just grabbing the cached copy), however on a form post IE6 SHOULD reload. Why are you adding the _doPostBack as an attribute, those should be autogenerated on any asp.net control that needs to post back.