# asp net 4 - autopostback doesnt fire in ie6

Tags: asp.net

OK, Im really stumped and hoping this is something simple.  I have a form that relies on an autopostback of a radiobuttonlist to show or hide something.  This was really elaborate at first and working fine, until I tested in IE6.  The code below is as basic as I can get, all my code behind does is update the label to the radiobutton's selected value on click.  This works in IE7 and 8, but not in IE6, what gives?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"  CodeBehind="testpostback.aspx.vb" Inherits="Checkout.testpostback" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check1" Value="Check1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Check2" Value="Check2" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="none" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the generated javascript in your web page and probably it uses new features of javascript that couldn't be executed by IE6.

Chances are you can debug the javascript and see what happens.

Consider that IE6 in XP Sp3 is not the same as IE6 in earlier XPs and it has less problems.

Answer (score 1):

This came up in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206595/ie6-problem-with-postback-in-asp-net) question as well. It seems to be an IE6 bug.

Comment: @Pauli: I couldn't agree more.